# Ruby on rails: What is the most simple way to show one post per page with permalink

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Right now under my posts controller i have methods

```
 def main
    @post = Post.all
  end

 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I am wondering what is the most basic and simple way to show one post per page and have next and previous links to it. Here i am referencing to `main.html.erb` . So for instance just have `localhost:3000/posts` and under that page i can have next and previous links to browse through the post.

Would I be needing some kind of ajax to this? If not then how i can do this using simple activerecord and other elements of rails?

Note: After I click on next, i do need to have the permalink of the post in the url tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. Add previous and next method to your model

```
def previous
  posts = where('id > ?', id).limit(1)
  if posts.nil?
    nil
    else
    posts.first
  end
end

def next
  posts = where('id < ?',id).limit(1)
  if posts.nil?
    nil
    else
    posts.first
  end
end
```

and then in your view you could do something like this.

```
 unless @post.next.nil? #to show the link to the next post
   link_to @post.next
 end
 unless @post.previous.nil? #to show the link to the next post
   link_to @post.previous
 end
```

Anyhow this method isn't that optimized since you will add more two more database queries to get previous and next posts.

Comment: I am getting a `undefined method `next' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I change the if in the view to unless instead. So it's going to print out the link when only there exist the next or previous post.

Comment: I have create a sample that works.
It's at this github repo git@github.com:chawladev/product-sample.git. Try running this rails project up. And then browse to path /samples and then create some records up then goto the one of the record page you will see the links next or previous or both to do the navigation that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the gem will_paginate and set the default per page to 1, as in:

```
class Post
  self.per_page = 1
end
```

For more information about will_paginate:
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: yes but i dont get permalinks of the posts. I need to have the exact links.